# eventResizeStop and eventDragStop callbacks dont send the right event data with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/ to create a calendar where my user can indicate his disponibilities. I am sending events’ info into a hidden field. Everytime an event occurs such as clicking to delete an event, dragging an event or resizing an event, I am updating the data sent to the hidden field. I have been experiencing problems with two callbacks :
•   eventResizeStop
•   eventDragStop
Here are the two problematic callbacks in my fullcalendar.js file

```
eventResizeStop: function(event) {
      var all_events = $('#js-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
      console.log(all_events);
      var array_all_events = [];
      $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
          // console.log(value.start["_d"]);
          // console.log(index);
           var day         = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd');
           var start_time  = moment(value.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = moment(value.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
             // var id          = value.unique_id["_i"];
             var slot        = {
                day: day,
                start_time: start_time,
                end_time: end_time,
              };
              console.log(slot)
            array_all_events.push(slot);
           // console.log(array_all_events.length);
        });

      console.log(array_all_events);
       if (array_all_events.length == 0) {
          console.log("eventresize");
          $("#dispo_array").val("");
        }
        else {
          console.log(typeof(array_all_events));
          console.log("eventresize");
          $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
        }
    },

    eventDragStop: function( event ) {
      // console.log(event);
      var all_events = $('#js-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
      console.log(all_events)
      var array_all_events = [];
      $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
          // console.log(value.start["_d"]);
          // console.log(index);
           var day         = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd');
           var start_time  = moment(value.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = moment(value.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
             // var id          = value.unique_id["_i"];
             var slot        = {
                day: day,
                start_time: start_time,
                end_time: end_time,
              };
            array_all_events.push(slot);
            // console.log(array_all_events.length);
        });
       if (array_all_events.length == 0) {
          console.log(array_all_events);
          $("#dispo_array").val("eventdrag");
        }
        else {
          console.log("eventdrag");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(array_all_events))
          $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
        }

    },
```

Everytime one of these two events happen, I am collecting all the events in the calendar through  `var all_events = $('#js-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');` and then sending their relevant data in the right format to my hidden field.

The problem is that these callbacks are supposed to be triggered at the end of the resizing or the dragging of the event (thus the data sent should be the one relevant to the state of the events at the end of the dragging and resizing actions). However when I run my tests, I realise that the data sent to my hidden field are the one relevant to the beginning of these triggers : that is when the dragging starts and when the resizing starts. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Have you tried with `eventResize` and `eventDrop`?

Comment: your right it works with this two callbacks ! thanks

Comment: would you happen to know how to make the allDaySlots selectable ? I couldnt figure it out

Comment: Just like any other slot: `selectable: true,`

Comment: my selectable is already set to true, it's working for all the other slots but this one

Comment: I asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053159/cannot-select-alldayslot-with-fullcalendar if you have an idea